# How to handle versions of an Entity in Database Design

Tags: database-design, erd, version-control

I am working on a new project. The domain logic of the project is as follows:

A user uploads a file (Document) and gives a title, then another user comes along and (s)he also tries to upload a file with the same title. This is OK providing that the body of the document has differences.

How can I design my domain model so that my web application that will later consume the data can inform the user viewing a particular document "hey there is another version of this document".

Here is a simple ERD of what I have, but that obviously does not perform what I want above.

[image]

I would greatly appreciate any help and advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could keep them all in the same table, simply with a column to track version numbers:

```
documents
---------
  id (part of PK)
  version_number (part of PK)
  title
  file
  creator_id (FK to users.id)
  version_date (the date that this version is created - not necessary, but good to have)
  file
```

Your application will need to be capable of handling updating the version number of a document when a new record is added but it is a new version of an existing document. You also need to ensure that any document metadata (such as `Title`) changes are propagated to all related documents. You could do this by allowing document ID to not be unique, and the primary key is a combination of document ID and version number. Otherwise, it could be impossible to tell which record to update.

Another way would be to have a stub for document metadata and a separate table for all versions:

```
documents
---------
  id (PK)
  title
  creator (FK to users.id)
  (other metadata)

document_versions
-----------------
  id (PK)
  document_id (FK to documents.id)
  document_version_number
  file
  (other fields)
```

The second option is a slightly more complicated structure, but will give you better referential integrity because all version must be linked to a document stub by a foreign key.

Personally, I'd go with the second version.

Comment: I'd actually recommend the first version, as it allows for a document's title and creator/owner to change.  Consider an `IsCurrent` bit field, it makes querying simpler.

Comment: You can enter another version with increased version_number, but smaller version_date. Would you want to prevent this?